# Expectation and Variance - Married Couples

Tags: probability

This question is problem 42 from Chapter 7 of *A First Course in Probability*, 9th ed. by Sheldon Ross. A search didn't return any results, but it is still possible that the question is similar to one that has already been asked. In this case, links to similar questions would be appreciated.

> A group of 20 people consisting of 10 men and 10 women is randomly arranged into 10 pairs of 2 each. Compute the expectation and variance of the number of pairs that consist of a man and a woman. Now suppose the 20 people consist of 10 married couples. Compute the mean and variance of the number of married couples that are paired together.

(Ross 355)

There is probably a way to do this that involves a special kind of probability distribution, but I am having difficulty with the VitalBook edition of this book, as it seems there are formatting and other errors. I would do this problem as follows:

Let's find the mean number of married couples paired together. I will assume that the arranging algorithm chooses each person with a uniformly distributed probability. The mean will be the expected number of married couples that are paired together. The expected value is determined by finding the sum of the products of the possible number of married couples times the probability of that number occurring. Ross writes this as $E[X] = \sum_x xp(x)$.  Under the conditions, it would seem possible that the result of such an experiment would be approximately normal. Let us form a one-to-one correspondence between the integers in the interval $[1, 10]$ and the men, and a similar correspondence between the integers in the interval $[11, 20]$ and the women. Henceforth, when I refer to an integer in the interval $[1, 20]$ without context, I mean the person corresponding to that integer. Let us assume "married couples that are paired together" means that $x$ is paired with $y$, where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \in \left\{1, 2, 3, \dots, 19, 20 \right\}$ and $y \in \left\{1, 2, 3, \dots, 19, 20 \right\}$, and $x$ and $y$ are married to each other. We shall arrange the men and women such that man $n$ is married to woman $(n+10)$. Consider $1$. There are nineteen possibilities for the person with whom $1$ is to be paired to make a couple. Of these, exactly one will make the pair a married couple. Thus the probability of $1$ being paired to make a married couple is $\frac{1}{19}$. So the contribution of $1$ to the expected value will be $\frac{1}{19}$. Now consider $2$. With probability $\frac{1}{19}$, we have already paired him with $2$, in which case he will not contribute a nonzero amount toward the mean. With probability $\frac{18}{19}$, he has not been paired yet. Conditional on this probability, there is a probability of $\frac{1}{18}$ that he will be paired with $12$ and create a married couple. This possibility contributes $\frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18}$ toward the mean. Now consider $3$. With probability $\frac{1}{19}$, he was paired with $1$. With probability $\frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18}$, he was paired with $2$. With probability $1 - (\frac{1}{19} + \frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18})$, he has not yet been paired. Conditional on this probability, there is a probability of $\frac{1}{17}$ that he will be paired with $13$ to make a married couple. So this contributes $\left(\left[1 - (\frac{1}{19} + \frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18})\right] \cdot \frac{1}{17}\right)$ to the mean.

Looking at the sum so far, we have 
$$(1) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{19}\right) + (1) \left(\frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18} \right) + (1)\left(\left[1 - (\frac{1}{19} + \frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18})\right] \cdot \frac{1}{17}\right) + \cdots $$

It seems to me that this sum should have a tidy "closed form", if you will, that doesn't require doing twenty repetitions of this process. There could be a way that involves combinatorics. I imagine it probably involves factorials or binomial coefficients. Is there a resource that explains in more detail than simply giving the formula $E[X] = \sum_x xp(x)$?

Source

Ross, Sheldon. *A First Course in Probability*, 9th Edition. Pearson Learning Solutions, 12/2012. VitalBook file.

Comment: The answer listed in the back of the book is 100/19; 16,200/6137; 10/19; 3240/6137. That's fine, but I'd like to know how they arrived at those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's the long route.   I would not go that way, but rather make some use of the Linearity of Expectation.

Let's use indicator random variables.   Let $X_i=1$ if the couple of pair #$i$ is mixed, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Now whomever one of the members of the first pair will be, there are 10 of 19 posible partners to make the pair mixed.   Since the indicator variables are Bernoulli distributed: $$\mathsf E(X_1)~{=\mathsf P(X_1=1)\\=\tfrac {10}{19}}$$

The variables $X_i$ are identically distributed, so $\mathsf E(X_i)=10/19$ for all of them.   However, they are not independently distributed.   Still, by similar reasoning as above: $$\mathsf E(X_1X_2)~{=\mathsf P(X_1=1)\cdot\mathsf P(X_2=1\mid X_1=1) \\ = \tfrac {10}{19}\tfrac {9}{17}}$$

Then $\mathsf E(X_i)= 10/19$ for all $i\in\{1..10\}$, and $\mathsf E(X_iX_j) = 90/323$ and for all $i,j\in\{1..10\}^2, i\neq j$.

(NB: $\mathsf E(X_1^2)=\mathsf P(X_1^2=1)=\mathsf E(X_1)$ so $\mathsf E(X_i^2)=10/19$ for all $i\in\{1..10\}$ )

Now your task is to use these to calculate: $\mathsf E(X),\mathsf{Var}(X)$ when $X=\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i$. $$\begin{split}\mathsf E(X) &= \mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i)\\\mathsf{Var}(X) &= \mathsf E((\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i)(\sum_{j=1}^{10} X_j))-\mathsf E(X)^2\end{split}$$

It simplifies to a closed form rather more easily.

---

Do likewise for $Y_i$, the indicator random variable that a pair are married.